# Can we create ObjectProperty between subclasses using OWL API?

Tags: owl-api

This was created in protege. is it possible to create the same objectproperty between the subclasses as shown in the picture? and also is it possible to add their range and domain?

Is it possible for me to have a sample code.
Thanks ^_^
below is the link to the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlzl8.png

Answer (score 0):

The image isn't relevant of your problem/question.

**Is it possible to create the same objectproperty between the subclasses ?**

in short : Yes you can, but you don't want it.

```
define four classes  A B C D
B is a sub class of A
D is a sub class of C

define one object property OP_1 between A and C  (range & domain)
define one object property OP_2 between B and D  (range & domain)
```

If OP_1 and OP_2 have different names then there is absolutely no problem.

But you said that you want OP_1 and OP_2 be the same objectProperty; This is not a good deal :

1. Lets define OP_1 is equivalent as OP_2
2. Then you use an inference engine / reasoner on your ontology.

Has you have define a property on super classes, how the reasoner should understand the property between sub-classes ? It will understand them as the same as super-classes (or any classes it is bind to). In most cases the assertions(classes restriction, range, domain) on the sub-classes will just be ignore.

Protege and/or owl-api allow you to write it, but do not ensure consistency or specific behavior/meaning for you.

**What you should do :**

create a taxonomy of properties :

```
define OP_1 a sub property of the super property OP
define OP_2 a sub property of the super property OP

had domain/range of super class on OP

had domain/range of whatever you want on OP_1 and OP_2 using sub-classes.
```